# Autohotkey use special function Key

Tags: autohotkey

I recently got my new XPS 15, only to be rather annoyed that it doesn't have a skip media button on the keyboard. However, one of the function keys (F9) is left empty, so i thought that i would simply use Autohotkey to map the media next funtion to this Key. I wrote the simple program:

```
F9::
Send {Media_Next}
return
```

which does work. However, this requires me to press Fn + F9, as I almost always have function lock enabled. This is especially annoying considering that all the other media keys are mapped as special functions, so if i have function lock enabled i do not have to press the Fn key.

Does anyone know how to address the key that the keyboard maps to whatever would be the special function on the F9 key, or any other workaround that means i don't have to press the Fn key for either the play/pause key or the next media key?

Comment: Short answer: not easily possible. The keyboard hardware itself handles the logic for switching between the standard `f#` keys and their secondary functions (such as media keys), and as such, an AHK application on a computer cannot interact with the hardware logic of that particular device. It would be more possible to just remap a different secondary key (that does output smthng to the computer) to become the skip media key instead.

Answer (score 0):

I a blank script paste this lines and run it:

```py
#InstallKeybdHook
KeyHistory
```

A window will pop, press once <kbd>F9</kbd> (without <kbd>Fn</kbd>) and then press <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> to refresh, what appears is what you can bind as hotkey. For example my <kbd>F9</kbd> is a remap of <kbd>Launch_App1</kbd> which is "Open Explorer".

If you have trouble interpreting the output save it in a bin site (like [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/)) and link back to take a look.